# Tangent lines to the curve parameterized by $x = a \cos(t)^4$, $y = a \sin(t)^4$

Tags: trigonometry

The parametric equations of a curve are
$$x = a \cos(t)^4 \qquad y = a \sin(t)^4$$
where $a$ is a positive constant.

(i) Express $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$. (3)

(ii) Show that the equation of the tangent to the curve at the point with parameter $t$ is
$$x \sin(t)^2 + y \cos(t)^2 = a \sin(t)^2 \cos(2t) \qquad (3)$$

(iii) Hence show that if the tangent meets the $x$-axis at $P$ and the $y$-axis at $Q$, then

$$|OP| + |OQ| = a$$

where $O$ is the origin. (2)

My answer to the first part is $-\tan(t)^3 \cot(t)$.

I can't figure out the second part.

Comment: Hint. The slope of the tangent line is $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$

Comment: Cheers. I actually did try to find out the equation of the line in the slope intercept form using the gradient from part one, inserting values of x and y, then finding c in terms of a. Cannot prove the equation to the tangent in part 2 though.

Comment: Show your work..

Answer (score 0):

for the part a) the answer is slope = $\frac{dy}{dx}$$=$ $\frac{(4a sin^3(t))(cos(t))}{(4acos^3(t))(-sin(t))}$=$\frac{-sin^2(t))}{cos^2(t))}$=$-tan^2(t)$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Didn't bother myself with the cot in my answer to first. But that shouldn't change the outcome to the second part right? That's where I'm stuck :s

Comment: If you have the slope correct, then you will be able to do b)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pEi0m3g

Comment: I've got it! I was putting a.cos^4t alongside gradient and y intercept. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

part a$$x=a\cos^4 t\to \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=\cos ^2 t\\
y=a\sin^4 t\to \sqrt{\frac{y}{a}}=\sin ^2 t\\
\sqrt{\frac{y}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=\sin ^2 t+\cos ^2t=1\\
\sqrt{\frac{y}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}=1$$

Comment: Clarified. Thank you^^

Answer (score 0):

$$x = a \cos^4t \qquad y = a \sin^4t$$

This is what I got.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}
   =\dfrac{4a \sin^3(t) \cos(t)}{-4a \cos^3(t) \sin(t)}
   =-\dfrac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\tag{i}$$

\begin{align}
   y-a\sin^4(t) &= -\dfrac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}(x-a\cos^4(t)) \\
   y\cos^2(t) - a\sin^4(t)\cos^2(t) &= -x\sin^2(t) + a\cos^4(t)\sin^2(t)\\
   x\sin^2(t) + y\cos^2(t) &=a\sin^4(t)\cos^2(t)+a\cos^4(t)\sin^2(t)\\
   x\sin^2(t) + y\cos^2(t) &=a\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)[\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)]\\
   x\sin^2(t) + y\cos^2(t) &=a\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)\\
   \dfrac{x}{a\cos^2(t)}+\dfrac{y}{a\sin^2(t)} &= 1\tag{ii}
\end{align}

Hence 
the $x$-intercept is $P=(a\cos^2(t),0)$ and 
the $y$-intercept is $Q=(0,a\sin^2(t))$. So

$$OP+OQ = |a|\cos^2(t)+|a|\sin^2(t)=|a|\tag{iii}$$

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for this. I made a stupid mistake in the second part but the third one was bugging me out. 
Cheers^^